# Error in Parsing functions Calling Conventions using Libtooling ASTFrontendAction

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libtooling

I'm using Libtooling to parse Windows SDK headers but there is a problem in getting functions calling conventions, The libtooling always return `__cdell` for `WINAPI` or `__stdcall` calling convention which is the defualt calling convention of Win32 API's.

This is an input example

```
VOID
__stdcall
TestFunction (_In_ BOOLEAN is_valid);
```

This is my Function Visitor function of my `RecursiveASTVisitor`

```
    virtual bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl *func)
    {
        // ...
        if (m_AstContext->getSourceManager().isInMainFile(func->getLocation()))
        {
            if (func->hasAttrs())
            {
                auto stdcall = func->hasAttr<StdCallAttr>(); // always return False
            }

            const clang::FunctionProtoType * prototype = func->getType()->getAs<FunctionProtoType>();
            if (prototype)
            {
                auto stdcall = prototype->hasAttr(attr::Kind::StdCall); // always return False

                errs() << clang::FunctionType::getNameForCallConv(prototype->getCallConv()).str() << " "; // always return cdecl
            }


            func->dumpColor(); // But there is __attribute__((stdcall)) in dumped output!

        }

        // ...
    }
```

And finally output of `func->dumpColor();` for input example!

```
^
FunctionDecl 0x218c95bb6f0 <C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um\winnt.h:430:14, C:\ExampleInput.h:18:36> col:1 TestFunction 'void (BOOLEAN) __attribute__((stdcall))':'void (BOOLEAN)'
`-ParmVarDecl 0x218c95bb5c0 <col:20, col:28> col:28 is_valid 'BOOLEAN':'unsigned char'
```

I ran it with/without this options too, for compatibility reasons but no difference at all :-(

```
-fms-compatibility 
-fms-extensions 
-fms-compatibility-version=19
```

Any idea?

**Update**

I found the problem, It's because of defualt compile config of #Clang. It's 64-bit (in 64-bit toolchain), And it doesn't work with `__stdcall` in 64-bit mode
If I use the 32-bit version (or -m32 option) then it will works correctly

Any idea why it happens in 64-bit mode?

Comment: From [Microsoft's documentation on __stdcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019): `On ARM and x64 processors, __stdcall is accepted and ignored by the compiler; on ARM and x64 architectures, by convention, arguments are passed in registers when possible, and subsequent arguments are passed on the stack.`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I knew that but if the compiler ignored `__stdcall` in 64bit then it should become `__fastcall` or something like that not the `__cdell`.